# Sending HTTP GET Request Using PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, get

I use the following code to send a get request to boilerpipe java web api to extract the html contents into plain text of a website,i use telerivet webhook api to send and recieve messages to my server where the php file is located,the timeout provided is 10 sec,i get timeout always with this code,please help me out

```
if ($_POST['secret'] !== $webhook_secret)
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    echo "Invalid webhook secret";
}
else 
{
    if ($_POST['event'] == 'incoming_message')
    {
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $from_number = $_POST['from_number'];
        $phone_id = $_POST['phone_id'];

        // do something with the message, e.g. send an autoreply            
        header("Content-Type: application/json");

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
        'http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/extract?url=http://www.kvgengg.com&extractor=DefaultExtractor&output=text&extractImages='
        ));
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $content;

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks incorrect... `url=http://www.kvgengg.com&extractor=DefaultExtractor` If all of that and what follows is the URL, it would need to be encoded. If `extractor=` is a different parameter in the same URL, you should encode the `http://ww.kvgengg.com`. Still that may have nothing todo with your timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a syntax error as you have an extra parentheses in the url, I've removed it.

As well if you use `http_build_query` to pass in your parameter it should solve your problem

```
if ($_POST['secret'] !== $webhook_secret)
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    echo "Invalid webhook secret";
}
else 
{
    if ($_POST['event'] == 'incoming_message')
    {
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $from_number = $_POST['from_number'];
        $phone_id = $_POST['phone_id'];

        // do something with the message, e.g. send an autoreply            
        header("Content-Type: application/json");

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
            'http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/extract?' . 
            http_build_query(array(
                'url' => 'http://www.kvgengg.com',
                'extractor' => 'DefaultExtractor'
                'output' => 'text',
                'extractImages' => ''
            ))
        );
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $content;

    }
}
```

Comment: Brother Augwa,It Still Gives Me A TimeOut..Please have a look at this image of my test session http://postimg.org/image/xogn9axa3/ What I Actually Need is to send the Contents Of Variable $content as sms back to telerivet client ...Am I Missing Anything Here?It Works Fine For Static Replies,With The Following Code...header("Content-Type: application/json");
            echo json_encode(array(
                'messages' => array(
                    array('content' => "This is a static message!")

Comment: try outputting the curl url and opening it in your browser. I suspect the url you are using is incorrect, or the remote web service doesn't respond in a suitable amount of time.

Comment: I went to http://www.kvgengg.com and that website is extremely slow, so that's likely the source of the problem.

Comment: it seems the telerviet times out after 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes brother, the curl part works pretty well within the browser, is the implementation I used here will do my desired task(sending the curl output to user)? When I contacted telerivet team with this issue, they said to implement using asynchronous task, any idea?

Comment: perhaps you want to take the request as it comes in, save the data and then process it using a cron. Alternatively if you have access to [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) you could submit it as a background task and then eliminate the need for a cron.

Comment: Could you help me with sample code brother? Implementing the same script with gearman/cron.... Please

Comment: Brother Augwa,I made the script work by specifying the curl part of the script seperately,Have a look http://codepad.org/jxc3sWzK thanks for your help

Comment: Brother Augwa,The Execution of the script depends on the execution speed,it fetch the result if the script replies within 10sec else i suffer with timeout,since this is for my graduation project,i need reliability for demonstration, is it better to switch from php to node.js to overcome this hassle?instead of using gearman in which i'm not familiar with??

Comment: There's many ways you can do this. However you just need send your message outside of the "incoming_message" function and have it actually make a call out once the information is immediately available.